# passing an argument to a class method results in TypeError

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror

I'm having an issue, I'm building a class for scraping and I have a method payload, pasted below,

```
def payload(self, kw_list, year_start=2021, month_start=1, day_start=1, hour_start=0):
```

Afterwards I try and use the class to test it in another file, and when I run the following:

```
from google_trends_package.google_trends_utility import TrendsUtility

gTrends = TrendsUtility()

gTrends.payload(kw_list=['bitcoin'], year_start=2020, month_start=10, day_start=2, hour_start=5)
```

I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
payload() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year_start'
```

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Is `google_trends_utility` your library?

Comment: Can we see the full traceback?

Comment: Are there 2 different ```payload``` methods ? One in ```TrendsUtility``` and other somewhere else?

Comment: It seems like there's something missing. How does a `TrendsUtility` instance know to call **your** `payload` method? Is there some inheritance not shown here?

Comment: Turns out I made a dumb error. I renamed my package just google from google_trends_package, and it was not being imported properly. I'm all good now, not I just have the errors leftover in my class ha.